# Firefox 4, 5 hang on Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, firefox

I've been having a lot of trouble with Firefox 4 and 5 hanging on my Windows XP machine. I've often found a temporary solution of uninstalling and reinstalling. Recently I deleted my Firefox profile to get a clean start. But nothing seems a reliable solution.

The only plugin that I have is Firebug. My machine is a bit low on RAM, with only 2 GB.

Am I missing something? Any troubleshooting steps that you would recommend? I've come to expect Firefox to be very stable, and that has not at all been my experience lately.

Comment: Check to see if you have the latest video drivers. I understand that Firefox 4 and Firefox 5 are making heavier use of the video card than what Firefox 3 and prior did.

Answer (score 2):

It'd be a good start to discover why they're hanging. I'd expect due to memory use. You can use Task Manager to monitor their memory consumption as they run (look in the *processes* tab). Are you using websites that are particularly intensive (I've actually noticed gmail, for example, adds considerable load to my gf's old laptop)?

You said you need to reinstall them after a time - does this mean they're eatting up lots of storage space over time? This is the part of your question I find particularly weird..

My understanding is also that Firebug eats a lot of resources, like, a lot. Perhaps you could try disabling it when your machine's acting up. 2GB is kind of lean, but not insanely so, I don't think you NEED more memory.

Comment: I don't know that I *need* to re-install them, just that it seems to help when attempted out of desperation.